# In middle of the bash script next job/code takes time to trigger if first is completed

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting, batch-jobs

I have a script which have my codes:

```
# scheduling details for abc.sas, first status check after 1 hr , status check interval is 30 mins
execute "claimant.sas"
echo "execute function done for abc.sas"

execution_check "ERA_abc" "3600"

status_check "ERA_abc" "abc.log" "1800" "abc.sas" "3600"
echo "status check done for abc.sas"
echo
echo

# scheduling details for dce.sas, first status check after 1 hr , status check interval is 30 mins
execute "dce.sas"
echo "execute function done for dce.sas"

execution_check "ERA_dce" "3600"

status_check "ERA_dce" "dce.log" "1800" "dce.sas" "3600"
echo "status check done for dce.sas"
echo
echo

......
```

now my problem is once i trigger my bash script so ERA_abc starts to run once its get completed ERA_dce should run immediately but it sometimes take an hour to get trigger ?

can you help me to know the reason and solution ? Thanks

Comment: what do `execute`, `execution_check`, and `status_check` do?  What are they, shell functions or external commands?   without knowing what they do and how they do it and what bugs they might have or what dependencies they have that might cause them to stall, it's impossible to tell what might be causing delays.   The multiple uses of `"3600"` might be relevant, maybe it's some kind of timeout limit? 3600 is the number of seconds in an hour. and 1800 seconds is half an hour.

Comment: in short, this seems likely to be related to custom, in-house programs.   You'd be better off asking the people who wrote them (or your local sysadmins) than random strangers on the internet who have no access to your in-house software.

Comment: Try reducing 3600 to 0 here: 
execution_check "ERA_dce" "3600"